# rabbitmq shovel state always starting

Tags: rabbitmq

With the following rabbitmq config

```
[   {mnesia, [{dump_log_write_threshold, 100}]},
    {rabbit, [{vm_memory_high_watermark, 0.4}]},
    {rabbitmq_shovel,
        [{shovels,
            [{devShovel,
                [{sources, [{broker, "amqp://shoveluser:shoveluser@server2:5672"}]},
                 {destinations, [{broker, "amqp://shoveluser:shoveluser@localhost:5672"}]},
                 {queue, <<"queue">>},
                 {publish_fields,[{exchange,<<"DataExchange">>}]}
                ]
            }]

        }]
    }
].
```

and all of the relevant queues / exchanges declared I am able to start my rabbitmq server. However, when I check the shovel management, the plugin always displays starting as the state of the shovel. What causes this and is there any way to get more info ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to check the user is setup correctly on the brokers.